# Button will not react to padding or margin in CSS

Tags: html, css, web

I'm having an issue getting one of my buttons to react to either padding or margin in CSS.  The button stays at the very bottom of the div and does not react to any type of padding or margin within the class I assigned to the div.

HTML

```
<div class="topBorder">
    <h1>Matt</h1>
    <a href="#" class="aboutButton">ABOUT</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.aboutButton {
      color: white;
      padding: 800px;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-family: 'Ubuntu';
}
```

[Current Look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6BNN.png)

Comment: Did you try `display:inline-block`?

Comment: In general it's a lot more useful to show the problem with a minimum set of live code rather than screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `display:inline-block` to your css button. This should allow it to be adjusted as needed. A div is by default a block level element and as such takes up the full available width. Inline elements take up only as much space as needed. Inline-block allow elements to have a specific width and height.

See http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

Comment: Do you mean `inline-block`?

Comment: @jcuenod probably, I'm not HTML expert. I thought it was just inline, it could be inline-block however.

Comment: @jcuenod yup thats what I meant. Just checked. My bad! Thanks.

Comment: that seemed to make some difference, but I'm still not able to move the button up.  I changed the button background-color to red and the button is expanded all the way from the left side to the end of the word in the button "about" which I obviously don't want.